# Django Urls conflict

Tags: django

In my App urls.py i have a urls conflict, every one is pointing to a different View, they have same syntax but one have a

**urls.py**

```
path('dashboard/categories/<str:category_name>', views.CategoryProductsView.as_view(), name='category_products')
path('dashboard/categories/add_category', views.AddCategoryView.as_view(), name='add_category'),
```

When i disable (comment) the first one the second url works fine , that's why i think that the problem comes from a url conflict

Comment: By looking at your code it seems to me that a comma is missing at the end of the first path.

Comment: Just change the order and put `add_category` at the top of `<str:category_name>` then it will work.

Comment: @HoseinRemezan thank you , that solves the problem

Answer (score 2):

The parameter that add_category expects is an integer? if so, specify it and put it before the string, possibly this way it will work.

```
path('dashboard/categories/<int:id>', views.AddCategoryView.as_view(), name='add_category'),
path('dashboard/categories/<str:category_name>', views.CategoryProductsView.as_view(), name='category_products')
```

Another simpler option is to modify the url of "add_category" and leave it as follows. This way it will not fail. (Take care with order)

```
path('dashboard/categories/add/add_category', views.AddCategoryView.as_view(), name='add_category'),
path('dashboard/categories/<str:category_name>', views.CategoryProductsView.as_view(), name='category_products')
```